# How is PICA different from other heat shielding materials?

Tags: spacex, reentry, atmospheric-drag, dragon, heat-shield

What are the differences and why did SpaceX prefer to use PICA?

[image: Image of Dragon Spacecraft with PICA - X heat shield.]

Comment: Interesting question! Is it possible to add a link or reference to a source supporting that SpaceX does use PICA? How do we know this is true? *Thanks!*

Comment: When NASA invented it, the claim was that it was lighter and cheaper. I guess that worked out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PICA is less dense than other materials and enables a lighter heatshield.

- [Phenolic Impregnated Carbon Ablators (PICA) as Thermal Protection Systems for Discovery Missions](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19970017002/downloads/19970017002.pdf)

Previous materials like fully-dense Carbon Phenolic (heritage entry grade Carbon Phenolic) used on more extreme missions like Pioneer Venus and the Galileo probe are propbably overkill for a LEO entry and are no longer capable of being produced:

- [Thermal Protection System Options For Outer Planet Probe Missions, OPAG, January , 10-11, 2013, Atlanta, GA, Presented by: Don. Ellerby](https://www.lpi.usra.edu/opag/meetings/jan2013/presentations/9_Ellerby.pdf)

It doesn't hurt that NASA *strongly supported* SpaceX in making its cargo Dragon heatshield:

- [Academy Sharing Knowledge, The NASA Source for Project Management and Engineering Excellence | APPEL, Fall 2010 edition](https://www.nasa.gov/pdf/489060main_ASK_40_Fall_2010.pdf)